# Best way to replace certain characters throughout a text file?

Tags: vim, text, emacs, vi, gedit

Is there any good Vim/Emacs/gedit shortcut to replace every certain character? Lets say I had the word "Hello, world!" and replace every 'l' character with 'r' so the statement would be "Herro, worrd!". I have a pretty big file to edit so I thought Vim or Emacs would have some fancy built in tricks to help me out :)

Comment: Using an editor for this kind of task is ... unconventional.  For a large file, the overhead of loading the entire file into memory and allowing for interactive editing is going to consume orders of magnitude more resources than a simple block I/O filter like `tr` or `sed`.

Comment: @tripleee - "orders of magnitude"? Could you back that up with some concrete numbers? No, maybe a bit slower, but not "orders of magnitude". I cannot speak in general for editors (so many of them nowadays), but Vim is actually pretty good at handling large files. At least has been in my experience (files the sizes of =<10 Gb). Another editor which actually prouds itself in fine handling large files is EmEditor.

Comment: Well, depends on what a "pretty big" file means, but if it won't fit into memory all at once, using an editor is certainly going to be several orders of magnitude slower and memory intensive than a simple filter.  But already if the file is more than ten buffered reads, we are talking about one order of magnitude. Regardless of the editor's memory allocation strategy, the unsaved changes will need to be buffered separately, which would already require a doubling of resources even in the ideal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vi

```
:%s/l/r/g
```

command line:

```
tr l r < in > out
```

Answer (score 1):

Emacs:

```
alt-% l RET r RET
```

which calls the function `query-replace`, which you can call like this

```
alt-x query-replace RET l RET r RET
```